# External Library Files in IBM Rhational Rhapsody

Tags: rhapsody

Where can additional libraries/Object files be added in Rhapsody to avoid errors while building the code?

For instance: scanf/Printf commands don.t show any error as it is able to access the respective libraries. Is there any specific location where Rhapsody Looks for the Libraries? Can we add our external Librries there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding the libraries in the **Libraries** field of the Features dialog for the relevant component in Rhapsody ?[image]

Comment: Yes I did. But,it didn't work. I am compiling it for Linux Environment .

Comment: In the generated makefile, do you see the libraries you specified in the line that begins "LIBS=" ?

Comment: I am not able to generate a make file because it shows me an error saying; functionXYZ() has multiple defination. However, I have checked carefully there isn't multiple definations in my C file. I am working on Linux enviroment and have Object files/C files of functions that I wish to use in my Rhapsody project

Answer (score 0):

What kind of error do you get?

If it is a compiler error then you need to add an "Include Path:" to find the headers of your library. This can be done in the General tab of your Rhapsody component.

If it is a linker error then you need to specify your library in "Library:" section of the General tab of your Rhapsody component. In the Properties tab you may specify a path to your library location.

Comment: It is a linker error. So, i did add my Object file in library path to make it have access it.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to add external libraries. However, for one another library it shows an error:  functionXYZ() has multiple defination. First defined here.....

Comment: Then you need to figure out which libraries contains this funktion. The name of the functionXYZ() should give you a hint what library is included twice.

Could you provide more detailed informations in the futur to better respond to your problem. Those general formulations don't help much for helping you.

Comment: Sorry for general formulation. I had two files. One to access GPIO pins and other for Sensor. I created library files for both. When I added library file for GPIO to the Path column in Rhapsody, and compiled it for Linux it showed no error. But doing the same thing for Sensor file shows following error::
/home/pi/rhp_projects/ExtFiles/NewAttempt2906/libRhp.a: In function `_fini':
:(.fini+0x0): multiple definition of `_fini'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/6/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/crti.o:(.fini+0x0): first defined here
& many more.This are system files,I havent defined them anywhere.

Comment: You mean you add only the sensor library (without the GPIO library) and you get this linker error?
Stupid question: Does your Sensor library contain a main function?

Comment: I have created another C file which has main function and then I use it to compile my Sensor Library file. I did the same for GPIO.

Comment: thank you for your help. I was able to rectify the error. I had included c file as well as object file for same , while making a library which caused the error.

Comment: Nice to hear that it finally works for you.
I hope you will have some fun with Rhapsody now.